# Data management / calculations when using PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am developing an application on `iOS` and `Android`. The application uses Bluetooth (standard Bluetooth not BLE) to send/receive information. It may not be of relevance but for reference my current test device is a Nexus 5.

The application is built with `Cordova` (or `PhoneGap`) so the UI is HTML5/JavaScript/css and the Bluetooth plugin is written in native (Java for Android, Obj-C for iOS). Futhermore the UI was created with the help of `Bootstrap`, `jQuery`, `Backbone.js` and `Underscore.js`.

My question is regarding the management of the Bluetooth data coming in. I haven't developed it yet, but I wish to have a Bluetooth listener service running, that will be able to perform calculations on the Bluetooth data being received. Before start, I kind of wanted to get an idea of my options and an idea of what the best method of attack would be. I could write a plugin to manage the data received, so that the data would be dealt with by native code (which to my knowledge would run smoother).

However, since my application is multi-platform (currently only iOS and Android but possibly more platform in the future) it makes more sense to me trying to tackle the data calculations without using plugins/native. Would it be feasible to attempt this in JavaScript? I've heard it can be quite laggy and cause timing issues within Cordova/PhoneGap applications when you increase the complexity.

Does anyone have any experience with this and may be able to shed some light? It would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a plugin that interfaces with a BT printer and found that the best performance was achieved with handling all calls and logic in a background thread. If not, the UI performance suffered greatly.

It is was not desirable to have to write everything twice in each native language, but the performance gain was well worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is as I expected. Is there by any chance that I could have a look at some of your sample code for this or is there anywhere you could point me to which has an example similar to this? I have attempted it but I seem to be missing something as I can't get it working properly.